# Flask app on Pythonanywhere - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

Do you know what is the problem with my flask app deployed on pythonanywhere? 
When I am trying to visit endpoint browser return me error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was
>   unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
>   there is an error in the application.

Error log:

```
2018-05-02 18:06:51,507:   File "/home/jobad/.virtualenvs/deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2018-05-02 18:06:51,507:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-05-02 18:06:51,507:   File "/home/jobad/scrapping/app.py", line 75, in antal
2018-05-02 18:06:51,507:     antal_export('Antal')
2018-05-02 18:06:51,507:   File "/home/jobad/scrapping/antalpl.py", line 100, in antal_export
2018-05-02 18:06:51,507:     with open( 'export/%s.csv' %company_name, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8' ) as csvfile:
2018-05-02 18:06:51,508: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'export/Antal.csv'
```

function code here:

```
def antal_export(company_name):
    global a
    test = []

    for document in a:
        event_obj = {}
        event_obj['company_name'] = document['company_name']
        event_obj['category'] = document['category']
        event_obj['offers'] = document['offers']
        test.append( event_obj )

    try:
        os.remove( 'export/%s.csv' %company_name )
        with open( 'export/%s.csv' %company_name, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            fields = ['category', 'offerts']
            writer = csv.DictWriter( csvfile, fieldnames=fields, delimiter=';' )
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows( test )
    except:
        with open( 'export/%s.csv' %company_name, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8' ) as csvfile:
            fields = ['company_name', 'category', 'offers']
            writer = csv.DictWriter( csvfile, fieldnames=fields, delimiter=';' )
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows( test )

    a = []
```

and folder tree:

```
(deploy) 18:06 ~/scrapping (master)$ ls
Procfile     antal2.py   experispl.py     graftonpl.py  infopracapl.py    pracapl.py     requirements.txt
__pycache__  antalpl.py  export           hayspl.py     manpower.py       pracujpl.py    static
all.py       app.py      goldenlinepl.py  hrkpl.py      michaelpagepl.py  randstadpl.py  templates
```

On heroku everything works great but I can't use it- it's a scraping app and some request are longer than 30 sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PythonAnyWhere, ensure that you provide the full path of the `.csv` file (you will need to specify the full path for any file you are using such as a `.db` or `.txt` file). Based on your provided traceback and folder tree it should be:

```
path = '/home/jobad/scrapping/export/{}.csv'.format(company_name)
```

Which in turn can be used for all your actions requiring the file:

```
os.remove(path)
with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
   ...
```